# Is it possibe to open BottomSheetDialogFragment above everything except one view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` with different states.

What I want to achieve is that the dialog should expand over everything, **except** default Android navigation bar + custom bottom navigation view.

So bottomsheet should be opened above bottom navigationView

[image: BottomSheet covering everything except bottom navigation view]

Any ideas?

Comment: BottomSheet like google maps?

Comment: @Faisal yes, like when you open google maps underground metro pin